# Performance - Having checkbox in each row of html table

Tags: html, performance, checkbox, html-table

To achieve multiple row selection in html table, traditionally all are using checkbox in each row. Will this affect the table (large amount of data) rendering (performance)? I have seen that some web apps achieved this by having div with border and some CSS class applied to selected rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: No *a checkbox* won't affect the performance for browser to render it.

Things that affect performance are images, external resources, iframes, loaded JS/CSS files, etc.
Use the [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) addon to find out what is affecting the performance and how to improve it.